# Differential Equations Show

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

A certain substance is formed in a chemical reaction. The mass of the substance formed t seconds after the start of the reaction is x grams. At any time the rate of formation of the substance is proportional to $(20-x)$. When $t=0, x=0$ and $dx/dt=1$

Show that x and t satisfy the differential equation $dx/dt=0.05(20-x)$
Don't know how to go about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the rate of formation is proportional to $20-x$, we are in effect told that $$\frac{dx}{dt}=k(20-x)$$
for some constant $k$.

When $t=0$, we have $x=0$ and $\frac{dx}{dt}=1$.

It follows that $1=k(20-0)$, and therefore $k=\frac{1}{20}=0.05$.